# Incorrect syntax near 'value'

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm attempting to add a record to DB by using Windows Form Application.
When i debuging the code, I get an exception: Incorrect syntax near 'value'
Sorry for the mess in the code, I'm a new member.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial   Catalog=VirtualSalesFair;Integrated Security=True");
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into Empty value('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + textBox2.Text + ",'" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" +textBox9.Text +"',"+textBox10.Text +");", con);
     int o=sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show(o+ ":Record has been inserted");
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: @codingbiz `Empty` is not a [reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Change your `Value` to `Values`

- [`INSERT (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

And please use *[parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of string concatenations are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial   Catalog=VirtualSalesFair;Integrated Security=True"))
{
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Empty VALUES(@VAL1, @VAL2, @VAL3, @VAL4, @VAL5, @VAL6, @VAL7, @VAL8, @VAL9, @VAL10)", con);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL1", textBox1.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL2", textBox2.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL3", textBox3.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL4", textBox4.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL5", textBox5.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL6", textBox6.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL7", textBox7.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL8", textBox8.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL9", textBox9.Text);
   sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL10", textBox10.Text);

   int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answre, i get the exception in this line:  int o=sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); I tried your suggestion and I still get the same exception.

Comment: @Nizan I missed the table name. Try it again.

Comment: Hi, I have a new exception: Incorrect syntax near rhe keyword 'VALUES'

Comment: Yes, I tried. Now i get this exception: Invalid column name 'VAL10'.

Comment: @Nizan I forget `@` before `VAL10`, use it like `@VAL10`. Take a look at again in my answer please.

Comment: I correct that, now i have this exception: Invalid object name 'Empty'. What am i doing wrong? i did exactly what i have seen in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3j-7309ITc

Answer (score 3):

Change value to values. So:

```
insert into empty values("...
```

This is the correct SQL syntax for inserting a row.

Comment: Yes, I want to insert a row. I build table and Form, i want by clicking on button in the form to insert a new row into SqlDB.

Comment: No. I don't know why it's doesn't work. It's should be simple code. I scratch my head and i'm still at the same place.

Comment: OK, what error are you getting now? Your code needed to be fixed to say values instead of value and that's the fix for the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

use `VALUES` instead of `Value`. A very common syntax mistake.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to de this code(See 2:05): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3j-7309ITc